# Instagram API gives oauthexception

Tags: swift, xcode, instagram-api

I am developing a iOS app and I am trying to integrate Instagram API into my app so user can login with instagram, but I am getting a error message saying you must include a valid `client_id`, `response_type` and `redirect_uri` parameters

it is working at the first time I run my project but after I restart my Mac it keeping getting this error when I run it.
below is the code that I have

```
let url = String(format: "%@?client_id=%@&redirect_url=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True", arguments: [INSTAGRAM_IDS.AUTHURL,INSTAGRAM_IDS.CLIENTID,INSTAGRAM_IDS.REDIRECTURL,INSTAGRAM_IDS.SCOPE])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class name Constant and add these things init

and watch this video on youtube 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zB50DMlVRgE

```
import Foundation


struct  INSTAGRAM_IDS {
    static let AUTHURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
    static let APIURL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
    static let CLIENT_ID = "id of client signup in insta and get id"
    static let CLIENTSERCRET = "secret of client signup in insta and get this"
    static let REDIRECT_URI = "http://www.google.com"
    static let ACCESSTOKEN = "access_token"
    static let SCOPE = "follower_list+public_content"
}
```